# Magento Configurable product being added as Simple Product

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

When adding a configurable product after choosing the required options, it adds the simple product to the cart which shows only the name/title of the simple product. This only happens from the product page, but when added through quick-view, it adds the configurable product and shows the options that were selected. How do I make it add the configurable product and show the options on the product page?

Simple Configurable Product module installed (tried without it, same problem)
Using Magento ver. 1.9.2.2 with Novaworks Bella theme.

Comment: The SimpleConfigurableProducts module hasn't been updated in over 3 years, so I wouldn't suggest you use it. There are however a couple of forked versions on GitHub that are still maintained.

Comment: @RobbieAverill Thanks for your help. I uninstalled it again, and now its adding fine.